# Lambda expression conversion from a method

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to write a filter method and a method that uses that filter method, also taking in the times. This class represents a text message database. I want to implement my filter method that takes in a Predicate filter, using a lambda expression in the getMessagesBetween method. However, I have no idea how to even begin with this. I know the general format for a lambda expression is 
(param) -> some logic, but I have no idea how to implement it here.
Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
public List<Message> filter(Predicate<Message> filter) {
    ArrayList<Message> filteredList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        if(filter.test(message)) {
            filteredList.add(message);
        }
    }
    return filteredList;
}

public List<Message> getMessagesBetween(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
    ArrayList<Message> messagesBetween = new ArrayList<Message>();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        LocalDateTime date = message.getDate();
        if(date == start && date == end) {
            messagesBetween.add(message);
        }
        if (date.isAfter(start) || date.isBefore(end)) {
            messagesBetween.add(message);
        }
    }
    return messagesBetween;
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @sgrillon please do not inline screenshots of code.

Comment: @luk2302, do not put external link

Comment: @sgrillon do I have to get a moderator involved here, **stop inlining the image of code**.

Comment: @luk2302, do I have to get a moderator involved here, **stop put external link.**

Comment: Can anyone provide help? I added the code instead of the images. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
public boolean isBetween(Message message, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
            LocalDateTime date = message.getDate();
            return date == start || date == end || (date.isAfter(start) && date.isBefore(end)) 
}
List<Message> filtereds = messages.stream().filter(message -> isBetween(message,start,end)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```